# Debootstrap script installs, but xorg only starts as root

Tags: bash, root, xorg, chroot, xserver

My Devuan debootstrap scripts work, but xorg only wants to start if I am the root user. You might have heard problems with xorg a million times, but I can't see what I am missing.

The scripts are on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/RobinWils/devuan-debootstrap-scripts).

---

The user is part of the following groups: `cdrom,console,floppy,sudo,audio,video,plugdev,netdev,tty,input`

The installed xserver packages are:
`xserver-xorg-video-dummy xserver-xorg-input-void xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-legacy xinit x11-xserver-utils xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Run my scripts at your own risk. It is not complete yet and might break stuff.

---

Script explanation:
 - The config script contains all the variables which you can set;
 - The install script runs debootstrap and mounts the folders;
 - The chroot script gets executed in the chroot;
 - The after-install script gets executed after the chroot script.

---

Log:

```
[   275.092] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[   275.096] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   275.097] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   275.098] Current Operating System: Linux thonkpad 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64
[   275.098] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=5a011253-6c0b-4520-85ba-28d2115369f6 ro quiet
[   275.100] Build Date: 03 November 2018  03:09:11AM
[   275.101] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   275.102] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   275.104]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   275.104] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   275.108] (==) Log file: "/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Oct 29 17:16:25 2019
[   275.109] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   275.109] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   275.109] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   275.109] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   275.109] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   275.109] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   275.109] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   275.109] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   275.109] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   275.109] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   275.110] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
[   275.110]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   275.110] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   275.110]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   275.110] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   275.110]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   275.110] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   275.110]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   275.110] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[   275.110]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   275.110] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   275.110]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   275.110] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   275.110]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   275.110] (==) FontPath set to:
    built-ins
[   275.110] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   275.110] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   275.110] (II) Loader magic: 0x55664db3ae00
[   275.110] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   275.110]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   275.110]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[   275.110]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   275.110]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   275.110] (++) using VT number 1

[   275.110] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: The name org.freedesktop.login1 was not provided by any .service files
[   275.110] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   275.110] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   275.113] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:221e rev 6, Mem @ 0xb3400000/4194304, 0x80000000/536870912, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   275.113] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:11fc:17aa:221e rev 161, Mem @ 0xb2000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   275.113] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   275.113] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   275.114] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   275.114]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   275.114]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   275.114] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   275.114] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   275.114] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   275.114] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   275.114] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   275.114] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   275.114] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   275.114]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.19.2
[   275.114]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   275.114]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   275.114] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   275.114] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[   275.114] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   275.114] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   275.114] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   275.114] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   275.114] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   275.114] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   275.114] (II) Unloading vesa
[   275.114] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   275.114] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms



[   275.114] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   275.114] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
[   275.114] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   275.114] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   275.114] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"


Fatal server error:
[   275.114] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   275.114] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   275.114] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   275.114] (EE) 
[   275.157] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Try ‘chmod u+s /usr/bin/Xorg’

Comment: That did not fix it. Here is the log: https://privatebin.net/?3b704b781ff62f85#hGiXcNiTi5y7mSLh2GCFJ4yp6hzzmPiATRwEofCdXS7

Comment: I see you've pasted a link in the comments here and used one in your other question. Try not to use links to other websites. Also, please accept answers if it solves your problem. Other users will find it helpful to know if something worked for you or not.

Comment: I don't have enough points to use images, so I had to use links. None of my questions had the solution which I am looking for. 

I will post the solution when I have it. I won't mark anything as a solution if it is not a solution, unless it helps me enough to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must allow anybody to start X11:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
# Xwrapper.config (Debian X Window System server wrapper configuration file)
#
# This file was generated by the post-installation script of the x11-common
# package using values from the debconf database.
#
# See the Xwrapper.config(5) manual page for more information.
#
# This file is automatically updated on upgrades of the x11-common package
# *only* if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of that package.
#
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command as root:
#   dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
allowed_users=anybody
```

Note that you have to run `dpkg-reconfigure x11-common` after you've created this file.

Comment: This helped me to discover that I had a problem with groups in my script. 

I will mark this as solution, since it might fix my problem. I have to fix my other problems first.

Comment: I don't want to allow "anybody". I don't think that it is great for security. The problem is not fixed. The new log is included in my question.

Comment: The user still hast to be member of the video and tty group, I think. And why wouldn’t you? You only can start X once and can’t kill processes of other users. Xorg files all have root owner ship as far as I know. I would love to hear your arguments :-)